# Implementing payed 3D models into Unity Games

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I've started learning gaming development using Unity and there's a thing I wasn't able to fully understand. I stumbled across the Sketch Fab website and noticed this cool market with 3D models and I was wondering what are the requirements to import such a model into an actual game.

For example this one already has animations:

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/royal-knight-895d1c1d222d4efd9f264318e8ab0cb2

But on the other hand others don't have:

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/crusader-knight-b079a8e34f454836bc8107c21c8c47fe

I have basically 2 questions:

1. If I buy the first model is this going to save me a lot of time and I can jump straight into implementing the character into an actual game and add custom scripts to it etc?
2. If I buy the second one, what would I need to too to actually animate this character? Is this something that somehow I can learn from Unity tutorials or would I need to import it to a tool like Blender to further improve this model with animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question provokes a lot of answers. The first model you show does have a .fbx format and the animations will hopefully work fine. This format is typically what you want to use with Unity.

The second model is **not** Rigged (look at the product description). What this means is you will have to rig every bone yourself (in Blender) and make it compatible with Unity. I never buy a model that isn't rigged.

To add animations to the second character, you can download some from www.mixamo.com or use many of the animations you will find in the Unity Asset Store.

Personally, I prefer getting my models from www.turbosquid.com.  You can search against multiple formats including .unitypackage

Answer (score 1):

As Jiveturkey said, the first model is directly compatible with unity and doesn't require any additional steps - so if you're looking to focus solely on building the game without worrying about animation then you might want to go with the first model.

The second model isn't rigged, so you would have to manage all rigging and animating yourself - Unity does have a built-in rigging package, so you would be able to do that within unity rather than using Blender ([Link to tutorial for rigging in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ss70u2-SvGw), [Rigging tutorial directly from unity](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/working-with-animation-rigging))

Unity can read .fbx, .dae (Collada), .3ds, .dxf, .obj, and .skp files for 3D models, and that's pretty much the only requirement. There are tons of sites with free 3D assets if you don't want to spend the money as well [Itch.io](https://itch.io/game-assets/tag-3d), [Unity Asset Store](https://assetstore.unity.com/?category=3d&free=true&orderBy=1), and tons more - these are just the ones that come to mind